# Undifferentiated attribute in <input tag: What purpose does it serve?

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to troubleshoot an auction script and ran into the following `<input` tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_end" {CUSTOM_END}>
```

where the template variable {CUSTOM_END} may = checked, 0, 1 or null ''

I cannot find this usage in html documentation. I see that all attributes of tag input must be defined, ie value="something" type="text" etc

What is the purpose of the undeclared template variable?  Is this a non-standard usage?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: `checked` is a boolean attribute, meaning its presence is all that is required. `checked="checked"` is the XHTML way of doing it, but `checked="IMMA FIRING MY LAZER!"` will work just fine too.